# Unicorn path when pushed to Azure app service

Tags: unicorn

I'm doing some testing using Unicorn, working with the Helixbase NuGet project. I set up a CI build/release pipeline, and it pushed the code and content as expected, including the Unicorn serialization folder into App_Data/unicorn. When I hit the site, however, I get this error: "Access to the path 'C:\projects\Helixbase\src\Foundation\Serialization\serialization' is denied." Which makes sense since this is the local path, not the path out on the server, but what path would I use on Azure since there's no drive path in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Unicorn folder is in your `App_Data` folder, you should be able to set the target datastore to `$(dataFolder)\unicorn`.

Depending on how you configure and deploy it, it could be `$(dataFolder)\unicorn\$(layer)\$(module)` or something of the sort. You may have to experiment with the path a little bit, but as long as it's under the `App_Data` folder, the `$(dataFolder)` token will get the job done.

Comment: That was it...in my particular case it ended up being $(dataFolder)\unicorn\$(layer)\$(module)\serialization. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

The target datastore uses the `$(sourceFolder)` variable as prefix in the value used in the different Unicorn configurations. Instead of changing the target datastore value directly, you should patch the `sourceFolder` variable value as follows using the appropriate value for each of your environments:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="$(dataFolder)\unicorn" />
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

In this way, you are able to keep decoupled the dataFolder location and the Unicorn serialization folder location. While on deployed instances these two folders are usually nested (the `Unicorn` serialization folder under the `Data` folder), they are not always nested in a local environment setup where your local repository code and your deployed solution might be in different locations (for example if you deploy your compiled code in a separate folder on your computer, or in a Virtual Machine, or in a Docker container).